# Issues With UCanAccess driver

Tags: drivers, libreoffice

I've been trying to transfer .accdb and .mdb files onto my computer using the UCanAccess driver and it works but it seems that all of the queries I have are transfer in as tables and many of them are dropped completely.  Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Access queries are translated into views and  libreoffice shows them in the same place of the tables(obviously they will be read only).
UCanAccess may not be able to translate some of the queries, but it's improving version by version.
Use the console.sh in the distribution to see which queries ucanaccess can currently translate and execute.